# Fetching video array from cloudinary on React app

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

I have React web app with video hosting by cloudinary.  I want to know the methods for pulling a random video from cloudinary library or making array?  Database used is mongodb.

Here is code from VideoPlayer Component.  I get React Error 152 when I try to run.

```
export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
    state = {
       randomId: ''
    };
    componentDidMount() {
       this.randomId();
    }
    randomId = () => {
       axios
           .get(inDev ? devAPI.concat("v2/getRandomId") : baseAPI.concat("v2/getRandomId"))
           .then(data => this.setState({ randomId: data }))
           .catch(err => {
               console.log(err);
               return null;
           });
    };
    render() {
return(
           <div>
               {this.state.randomId.length === 0 ? (
                   <div>Loading...</div>
               ) : (
                   <div>this.state.randomId</div>
               )}
           </div>
    )
     }
}
```

Here is API

```
router.get("/v2/getRandomId", (req, res) => {

    cloudinary.search.max_results(1).execute().then(result=>{
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            data: result.resources
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Does array contains different video url?

Comment: What's the use case? I know Cloudinary doesn't have a feature to get a random video URL that you have hosted but doesn't mean that one can't be created.

Comment: I ended up creating a random number generator then assigning product of that variable to the Index value of video array to shuffle videos on every page load. Random number generator was placed in componentWillMount Method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a random number generator then assigning product of that variable to the Index value of video array carousel to shuffle videos on every page load. Random number generator was placed in componentWillMount Method to occur on every page load.

Thank you for all the help.